# Interactjs Drag and Drop - Can't drop in between overlapping dropzones

Tags: javascript

I am trying to drop a shape on its matching template. Template consists of multiple shapes joined together to create a figure. In some figures I am not able to drop my target in its matching template because it is overlapped with adjacent dropzones (Refer to the attached image). I cannot drop on the red triangle between two green zones.

[image]

```js
function setupDropzone(el, accept) {
    interact(el)
   .dropzone({                
       accept: accept,
       overlap: 'pointer',
       ondropactivate: function (event) { },
    ondropdeactivate: function (event) {}
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for this. Calculate the distance between centers of all drop areas and drag div in 'dragmove' callback and add a class to nearest drop area.
Then, use 'dynamicdrop' property to activate the required dropzone. This process happens continuously with dragmove.

```
$('.allowDrop').removeClass('allowDrop');
    var distArr = [];
    var elemPos = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var elemCenter = {};
    elemCenter.x = (elemPos.top + elemPos.bottom)/2;
    elemCenter.y = (elemPos.left + elemPos.right)/2;
    $('.js-drop').each(function(index, el) {                
        var dropPos = el.getBoundingClientRect();
        var dropCenter = {};
        dropCenter.x = (dropPos.top + dropPos.bottom)/2;
        dropCenter.y = (dropPos.left + dropPos.right)/2;
        var distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow((elemCenter.x - dropCenter.x),2) +
                                 Math.pow((elemCenter.y - dropCenter.y),2));
        distArr.push(distance);                         
   })
   var minDist = Math.min.apply( Math, distArr );
   var index = distArr.indexOf(minDist);
   $($('.js-drop')[index]).addClass('allowDrop');

   // setup drop areas.
   setupRemoveZone('.removeShape', '.js-drag');
   setupDropzone('.allowDrop', '.js-drag');
   interact.dynamicDrop(true);
```